# Prove $2^{135}+3^{133}<4^{108}$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, exponentiation, number-comparison

How can we prove the following inequality?

$$2^{135}+3^{133}<4^{108}$$

Comment: Why don't you just use a calculator and compare the results?

Comment: can he  calculate $2^{135}$?

Comment: @StefanH., the question says "prove the inequality"

Comment: @Vijay: If the question was " Prove the inequality $2^4+3^4<4^4$ ", would you still say that using a calculator is an invalid response? I don't think I would.

Comment: by prove, you mean prove by analytic methods. using a calculator is  known as 'verification'-checking your hypothesis

Comment: @VijayRaghavan: I disagree. Proving is verifying correctness. If explicit calculation can confirm this, then this a perfectly valid proof. On the other hand, this is most likely not what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Just try to answer this question with "checked with a computer/pocket calculator" in any decent mathematics department around the globe, and see what grade you get...I think it is *obvious*, in 99.98% of the cases, that what is meant here is a mathematical non/computerized proof. Furthermore, I both as a mathematician and a teacher am not willing to accept that a result based on using a calculator that I, or anyone I can rely on, haven't checked is "an explicit calculation". Do it the way Gauss, Euler did and get a 100 grade, though.

Comment: Based on the full numerical calculation (see @Ali below), the inequality can be made  more restrictive: $2^{135} + 3^{133} < 4^{106}$.

Comment: What if the problem is solved symbolically, but with the help of a computer algebra system? Is that more or less cheating than just working out the bignums? How about pencil and paper: is that not a persistent storage device which makes possible certain representations that augment what the brain can do?

Comment: @DonAntonio: If you are not willing to accept a calculated answer, you are not expecting mathematics from your students but something else.  Vijay is absolutely wrong that it is simply verification, and you are wrong that it is not a 100% valid mathematical proof.

Comment: Ok @ex0du5, so we're wrong just because you decided so... *sigh* . Anyway, it'd be nice and perhaps even funny to know what happens when students try that in college/university. For example, let me please know what universities accept their students using highly developed calculators to solve linear systems (matrices) or solve integrals in their exams...oh, and btw: I didn't mention anything about mathematical proof with any percentage of validity.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First,

$$2^{135}=2^7\cdot2^{128}=2^7\cdot(2^8)^{16}<(2^8)^{17}=256^{17}\;.$$

Next,

$$3^{133}=3^3\cdot3^{130}=3^3\cdot(3^5)^{26}=3^3(243)^{26}<3^3(256)^{26}=27\cdot256^{26}\;.$$

Thus,

$$2^{135}+3^{133}<256^{17}+27\cdot256^{26}=(1+27\cdot256^9)256^{17}<256^{10}\cdot256^{17}=256^{27}=4^{108}\;.$$

Comment: Aha! Very nice.

Comment: Excellent. Way to go!!!

Comment: Minor simplification: $27\cdot 256^{26}<2^5\cdot2^{8\cdot 26}=2^{213}$, thus $2^{133}+3^{133}<2\cdot 3^{133}<2\cdot 2^{213}=2^{214}=4^{107}$. This is quite close to the "true" exponent $\approx 105.4$.

Answer (score 17):

While there are several more clever answers up there, I couldn't resist posting this answer.

```
2^135 =                          43556142965880123323311949751266331066368
3^133 =   2865014852390475710679572105323242035759805416923029389510561523
4^108 = 105312291668557186697918027683670432318895095400549111254310977536
```

So even by eye, you can confirm that $2^{135}+3^{133}<4^{108}$.

Comment: Since the inequality is so far, and you can do it "by eye", perhaps we could consider using $\log_{10}$ along with estimates for the $\log_{10} 2, \log_{10} 3$ (and then $\log_{10} 4$ follows).

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams Yeah, sure.

Comment: Hm, one possible concern with eyeballing such long strings is that, without counting, are we sure that the string with less horizontal length has the least number of digits?  Depending on the formatting, some characters may take up less space than others.  It appears things are pretty equal here though.

Comment: @Jonas: how's that? Ali, I hope you don't mind the edit...

Comment: @JonasMeyer This would be an issue in written form or with usual font but Ali made sure to use a monospace one, which has the same horizontal and vertical space allocation for any kind of symbol.

Comment: @Mike I like it, thank you! $:)$

Answer (score 13):

Using $3^5 < 2^8$ we have $3^{130}<2^{208}$.

$$2^{135}+3^{133}< 2^{135}+3^{3}2^{208}<2^{208}+3^{3}2^{208}=(1+27)4^{104}<4^4 \cdot 4^{104} $$

Answer (score 10):

Note that $2^6<3^4$, so $$2^{135}=2^{129}2^6<2^{129}3^4<3^{129}3^4=3^{133}.$$  Therefore $$2^{135}+3^{133}<3^{133}+3^{133}=2\cdot 3^{133}<3\cdot 3^{133}=3^{134}.$$

Next note that $3^5<2^8$, so $$3^{134}<2^{134\cdot (8/5)}<2^{215}<2^{216}=4^{108}.$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** log$_2(3)\approx 1.5850$… Consider writing $3^{133}$ as a power of $2$ and factoring.

Comment: It is enough to use $\log_2(3)<8/5$, i.e., $3^5<2^8$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $4=2^2$ and $\frac {3^4}{4^4} \lt 3^{-1}$ - also that $108=4\times 27$

On dividing through by $4^{108}$ and working with the expression we find $$\frac {2^{135}}{4^{108}}+\frac {3^{133}}{4^{108}}=2^{-81}+3^{25}\left( \frac{3^4}{4^4}\right)^{27}\lt 2^{-81} + 3^{-2}\lt \frac 12+\frac 13\lt 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$3^{135} = 3^{5 \cdot 27} < 4^{4 \cdot 27} = 4^{108} \implies {2^{135}+3^{133}} < 3^{134} < {4^{108}}\;.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another one that uses the $$ 3^5 < 2^8 = 4^4 $$

and the easy to prove: $$2^{135} + 3^{133} < 3^{135}$$

Then:

$$2^{135} + 3^{133} < 3^{135} = (3^5)^{27} < (4^4)^{27} = 4^{108} $$

Answer (score 1):

Take logarithms, and don't worry about even large differences:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
135\log 2&\approx &93.57\\
133\log 3&\approx &146.12\\
135\log 2&<&133\log 3\\
108\log 4&\approx &149.72\\
\log[2^{135} + 3^{133}]&< &\log (2 \cdot 3^{133})\\
\log (2 \cdot 3^{133}) &\approx &146.81
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 0):

i would like different method,first let us  do following things

$2^{135}=2^{27}*2^{108}$

and $  3^{133}=3^{25}*3^{108}$

so we have

$2^{27}*2^{108}+3^{25}*3^{108}<4^{108}$

can't proceed from this?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you would suggest doing with this reformulation.

Comment: i just wanted to show if this way is clear

Comment: dato, I do not understand what your comment means.  If "way" means a way to solve the problem, I don't know what way you are suggesting.  There is a reformulation of the inequality, but I don't understand how it is being suggested that this reformulation could be used to prove that it is true.

Comment: if this method will show  anyway of solution,like $2^n+3^n<4^n$

Comment: That is a different inequality, which in the case of $n=108$, is much weaker. It is unclear to me how it would show a solution to this problem.  I have no doubt that one *could* start some solution with this observation, but it does not appear to be indicated *how* in this answer.

Comment: ok if it is bad,you can downvote  or i can delete it,no problem

Comment: @JonasMeyer The solution I posted deals with the $3$ part of the solution in a manner compatible with this, and the $2$ part is easily adaptable.

Answer (score 0):

$9=3^2>2^3=8 \implies 3^{90}>2^{135}$

$\begin{align}256=4^4>3^5=243 &\implies \\  
4^{108} &>3^{135} \\
&>3^{90}+3^{133}\\
&>2^{135}+3^{133}\end{align}$

Clearly we are a long way from having a close inequality there. The same approach would justify $2^{201}+3^{134}<4^{108}$